# Multiple target Xcode 7.3 iOS 9+ app Launch screen xib issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiimageview, ios9

I have a xcode project which multiple targets also have multiple image assets also.

All the UIImageView in app works fine and take respective images from specified target assets

But in LaunchScreen.xib I have added a UIImage which serves as my background image to it I assigned a Image from Image assets

```
|
|-Client1-ImageAssets (target 1)
| |-SplashScreen.jpg
|-Client2-ImageAssets (target 2)
| |-SplashScreen.jpg
|-Models (Multiple targets)
|-View (Multiple targets)
|-Main.Storyboard (Multiple targets)
|-LaunchScreen.xib (Multiple targets)
```

Above is just an overview.

In LaunchScreen.xib I have a UIImageView which is linked to SplashScreen.jpg

Please help

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I have to restart my phone/simulator to get it working.

Restart your devices and launch screens will be the new one. For every case you have to redo it. Even uninstalling and re-installing wont fix it.

Lost too much time on this one